# Azure Active Directory Active ActAs WCF

Tags: wcf, azure-active-directory, acs, ws-federation

I'm trying to create an MVC 5 app secured using WIF against Azure Active Directory. I'm trying to use SAML tokens with the following code:

```
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata, 
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                     SaveSigninToken = true
                }
            });
```

The plan is to use the returned token to pass through to a back end WCF service. From my investigations, I understand I would need to use the "active flow" here, where the web app will need to request an access token from Azure AD in order to authenticate with the WCF service.

Is this flow supported by Azure Active Directory? Everything I am ready seems to suggest it's not, and these days we are very much steered towards WebAPI / OpenIdConnect.

I'm really keen to get confirmation one way or another on whether this is possible (with WCF) or whether it's time to give up on this approach.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

That flow isn't supported by Azure AD. Furthermore, your impression is correct- there is no explicit support for WCF in Azure AD, and although it is technically possible to arm-twist WCF to use Azure AD tokens, it is very difficult and requires heavy customizations.
I highly recommend considering web API moving forward, you'll find that all of our samples and SDKs from the last 5 years or so are all predicated on that.